# How is the conversion from an operator equation to a c-number stocastic differential equation justified?

Tags: laser, quantum-optics, stochastic-processes

In many papers on laser dynamics theory, quantum Langevin equation of operators is converted to c-number stocastic differential equations, which is analyzed to obtain results. However, why this procedure is justified is not described in the papers, at least not satisfactory for me. I try to trace back to earlier literature, but still can't find a good explanation. Some of the papers I'm referring to are:

1. role of pumping statistics in laser dynamics Quantum Langevin approach, Phys. Rev. A
2. role of pumping statistics and dynamics of atomic polarization in quantum fluctuations of laser sources, Phys. Rev. A
3. laser theory with finite atom-field interacting time, Phys. Rev. A
4. sub-Poissonian processes in quantum optics, Rev. Mod. Phys.

Could anyone provide a brief answer? Or maybe direct me to a better reference.

Comment: Which many papers?

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to include the paper information in the post at the beginning. Titles of some papers have been appended at the end of the post.